# Azure Blob TIFF to PNG Conversion Without Download

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure

I'm trying to figure out a way to show a tiff image (pulled from Azure blob storage) in an `img` tag without using a tiff viewer. My first thought is to convert the image from a tiff to a png then show it in the browser as a base64 encoded image.

I've seen the `Image.Save` method being used a lot but I can't seem to figure out how to use it without saving the image to disk.

Is there a way I can convert the tiff to a png on the fly so it will render in browsers?

## Code to work from

public ActionResult Index()

```
{
    CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = GetContainer(documentsContainerName);
    IEnumerable<string> blobs = blobContainer.ListBlobs().Select(blob =>
    {
        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = (CloudBlockBlob)blob;

        using (MemoryStream blockBlobStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            blockBlob.DownloadToStream(blockBlobStream);

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (Image img = Image.FromStream(blockBlobStream))
                {
                    img.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
                }

                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ms);

                byte[] bytedata = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(reader.ReadToEnd());

                string strBase64 = System.Convert.ToBase64String(bytedata);

                return strBase64;
            }
        }
    });

    return View("Index", "", blobs);
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `System.Drawing` in ASP.NET code because it's a wrapper around GDI which is not supported in headless environments (ditto Office COM automation). This also applies to `System.Windows.Media` (a wrapper around WIC). Consider using a library like Magick.NET instead: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Magick.NET-Q16-x86/

Comment: That worked beautifully, thanks @Dai.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per @Dai's suggestion I was able to convert my blob to a png using [Magick.Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Magick.NET-Q16-x86/) nuget package.

```
using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (MagickImage image = new MagickImage(byteArray))
    {
        image.Format = MagickFormat.Png;
        image.Write(memStream);
    }
    return System.Convert.ToBase64String(memStream.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: The MagickImage class also has a `.ToBase64(MagickFormat.Png)` method that you could instead.

Answer (score 1):

as per documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142147(v=vs.110).aspx) you can create a memory stream and save the image directly to it, instead of the disk.

**Edit 1:**
Guessing that you're using some sort of API, you can return the string representation of that img, have your client side JS save it on the client machine cache and alter your `<img src=""/>` to the proper location...

**Edit 2:**
A better way would be, upon upload, convert the tiff to png and store it along and then only reference it as a regular blob on your page... this way you save a lot of CPU power cause you won't be converting tiff as needed, but only once.

Comment: That would still necessitate a download. You're not saving anything to the filesystem, but you'd still need to transfer the bytes to act on them.

Comment: @ChrisPratt That's true. I guess I meant that I didn't want to save it to my file system. Leonardo this is good to know but it doesn't help me with the other steps I'm trying to do. I need to be able to pull the image from Azure Blob Storage, convert it to a png, and display it to the browser.

Comment: @Leonardo I added some code to work from. It's giving me a timeout error on `ms` with this code `img.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);`

Comment: I agree that it would be better to convert it on upload but I don't have control over that. I added an answer that was what I needed. If anyone would like to take to improve upon it that would be great!